# Subquery optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, subquery

I was reading through this article - http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

I am working with an existing design.

What I want is to be able to select all id's from table a, which are not in table b.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM `orders` a LEFT JOIN `orders_corrected` b ON 
a.`order_id`=b.`order_id` WHERE b.`order_id` IS NULL;
```

Table a contains over 900K records and Table b contains over 200K and growing.

The above query takes about 7-8 minutes. I tried doing a `LIMIT 5` as well. but it doesn't help much.

I also tried using `NOT IN`, which is slow as well.

`order_id` column is NOT NULL and UNIQUE indexed.

Ouput of `show create table...`

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `order_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `order_data` text,
 `billing_address` text,
 `shipping_address` text,
 `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
 KEY `ix_order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Output of `explain`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: a
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 595783
Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: b
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,order_id_UNIQUE,ix_order_id
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 152
ref: func
rows: 1
Extra: Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `order_id` in both tables?

Comment: Add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` output for both tables. (what is the datatype of `order_id`? `VARCHAR(50)`? )

Comment: @ypercube Yes, both are indexed (unique key)...varchar 50

Comment: Edit the question and add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for both tables.

Comment: Edited. Have added the `SHOW CREATE...` for only one table as the other one is exactly the same.

Comment: Thnx. Two more questions: How many rows does the query return? Have you tried the `NOT EXISTS` version and what explain plan would that version have?

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders_created;` The issue is that this table does not have `latin1` charset but very probably `utf8`. That's one reason why the query is not efficient.

Comment: One of your tables does not seem to have indexes. Can you also post the output of show index (show index from orders; show index from orders_corrected;)